# No TabController for TabBarView in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:responsive_widgets/responsive_widgets.dart';
import 'package:pie_chart/pie_chart.dart';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Recipe extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RecipeState createState() => _RecipeState();
}

class _RecipeState extends State<Recipe> {
  TabController _tabController;
  bool toggle = false;
  Color selectedColor1 = Color(0xffff718b);
  Color selectedColor2 = Colors.black;
  Color cc = Color(0xffff718b);
  Map<String, double> dataMap = Map();
  List<Color> colorList = [
    Color(0xFFFFBD4B),
    Color(0xFF55CCD4),
  ];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dataMap.putIfAbsent("Leftover Ingredients", () => 75);
    dataMap.putIfAbsent("Used Ingredients", () => 25);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ResponsiveWidgets.init(
      context,
      height: 1920, // Optional
      width: 1080, // Optional
      allowFontScaling: true, // Optional
    );
    return ResponsiveWidgets.builder(
      height: 1920, // Optional
      width: 1080, // Optional
      allowFontScaling: true,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            ),
            title: TextResponsive(
              "Recipe",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'SofiaPro-SemiBold',
                fontSize: 50,
                color: Color(0xff130f10),
              ),
            ),
            centerTitle: true,
          ),
          body: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 450.h,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Positioned(
                        top: -5,
                        left: 20,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'Assets/recipe_details/Place Your Image Here.png',
                          height: 454.h,
                          width: 953.w,
                        ),
                      ),
                      // Adobe XD layer: 'Place Your Image He…' (group)
                      Positioned(
                        top: -10,
                        left: 840.w,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'Assets/recipe_details/Place Your Image Here.png',
                          height: 454.h,
                          width: 953.w,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        left: 30,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'Assets/recipe_details/Place Your Image Here (Double Click to Edit)-1.png',
                          height: 363.h,
                          width: 888.w,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        child: Image.asset(
                            'Assets/recipe_details/Vector Smart Object (Double Click To Edit).png'),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        top: -30,
                        left: 100,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'Assets/recipe_details/Place Your Image Here (Double Click to Edit).png',
                          width: 145,
                          height: 176,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Align(
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'Assets/recipe_details/kisspng-pizza-margherita-bacon-delivery-cheese-pizza-menu-5b2597bcabaf52.8918615115291903327032.png',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8,
                ),
                Center(
                  child: TextResponsive(
                    'Tomotto pizza',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'SofiaPro-Bold',
                      fontSize: 75,
                      color: const Color(0xff130f10),
                      height: 0.8,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                ),
                Center(
                  child: TextResponsive(
                    '35 - 40Minutes',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'SofiaPro-Medium',
                      fontSize: 40,
                      color: const Color(0x80282828),
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                DefaultTabController(
                  initialIndex: 0,
                  // The number of tabs / content sections to display.
                  length: 2,
                  child: TabBar(
                    controller: _tabController,
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 502.5.w,
                          height: 157.h,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                            ),
                            color: Color(0xfffffafb),
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                            child: TextResponsive(
                              'Ingrediants',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'SofiaPro-SemiBold',
                                fontSize: 50,
                                color: selectedColor1,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 502.5.w,
                          height: 157.h,
                          child: Center(
                            child: TextResponsive(
                              'Method',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'SofiaPro-SemiBold',
                                fontSize: 50,
                                color: selectedColor2,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ), // Complete this code in the next step.
                ),
                TabBarView(
                  children: [Text("data"), Text("data2")],
                  controller: _tabController,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      radius: 10,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                    ),
                    TextResponsive(
                      'Keep track my leftovers',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'SofiaPro-Light',
                        fontSize: 40,
                        color: const Color(0xb3130f10),
                        height: 1.5,
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                // Adobe XD layer: 'Rectangle 7 copy 21' (shape)
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Container(
                    width: 800.w,
                    height: 140.0.h,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      color: const Color(0xffff718b),
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                      child: TextResponsive(
                        'Add to menu',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'SofiaPro-SemiBold',
                          fontSize: 45,
                          color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                        ),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                Divider(
                  thickness: 1,
                ),

                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: TextResponsive(
                    'Price Breakdown',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'SofiaPro-SemiBold',
                      fontSize: 55,
                      color: const Color(0xff130f10),
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Center(
                      child: PieChart(
                    dataMap: dataMap,
                    animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                    chartLegendSpacing: 32.0,
                    chartRadius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.7,
                    showChartValuesInPercentage: true,
                    showChartValues: true,
                    showChartValuesOutside: true,
                    chartValueBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    colorList: colorList,
                    showLegends: true,
                    legendPosition: LegendPosition.right,
                    decimalPlaces: 1,
                    showChartValueLabel: true,
                    initialAngle: 0,
                    chartValueStyle: defaultChartValueStyle.copyWith(
                      color: Colors.blueGrey[900].withOpacity(0.9),
                    ),
                    chartType: ChartType.ring,
                  )),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Ing extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  final String string;
  final String data;
  Ing({this.string, this.color, this.data});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              // Adobe XD layer: 'Rectangle 9' (shape)
              Container(
                width: 25.0.h,
                height: 25.0.h,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.elliptical(12.5, 12.5)),
                  color: color,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              TextResponsive(
                string,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'SofiaPro',
                  fontSize: 45,
                  color: const Color(0xff130f10),
                  height: 1.3333333333333333,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          TextResponsive(
            data,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'SofiaPro-Medium',
              fontSize: 45,
              color: const Color(0xcc130f10),
              height: 1.3333333333333333,
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error

```
The relevant error-causing widget was
    Scaffold 
lib\recipe_details_5.dart:45
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#cbb99 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1694 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was
    Padding 
lib\recipe_details_5.dart:62
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
W/ActivityThread(18947): SCHED: com.project01withsauiux/.MainActivity [70, r=39ms, a=16ms, w=79911ms]
```

Answer (score 1):

See the code below, it may help you:

```
class _RecipeState extends State<Recipe> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{//changed
  TabController _tabController;

  ...

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dataMap.putIfAbsent("Leftover Ingredients", () => 75);
    dataMap.putIfAbsent("Used Ingredients", () => 25);
    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this, initialIndex: 0);//changed
  }

  ...
```